# Haskell Polymorphism on Datatype

Tags: function, haskell

I want to define a polymorphic datatype to represent expressions involving addition, multiplication and numbers

```
data Expr = 
  Number (Integer, Double)
  | Plus Expr Expr
  | Times Expr Expr
  deriving Show

expr1 = Times (Plus (Number (5.2 :: Double)) (Number 4)) (Number 2)
expr2 = Plus (Number (2 :: Int)) (Times (Number 3) (Number 4))
expr3 = Times (Number "hello") (Number "world")
```

I do also have the following test cases:

```
testEval1 = "Expected 18.4; eval expr1 returned " ++ show (eval expr1 :: Double)
testEval2 = "Expected 14; eval expr2 returned " ++ show (eval expr2 :: Int)
testEval = putStr (testEval1 ++ "\n" ++ testEval2 ++ "\n")
```

How would I define that in Haskell?

Comment: [GADT](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) How about that?

Comment: A number consists of an `Integer` and a `Double`? That's a mighty strange representation. Could you explain?

Comment: You could use `data Expr = NumberI Integer | NumberD Double | Plus Expr Expr | ...` so that you can store both kinds of constants in your expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794379/haskell-polymorphism-on-datatype#comment123371714_69794379), [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi) writes:

> You could use `data Expr = NumberI Integer | NumberD Double | Plus Expr Expr | ...` so that you can store both kinds of constants in your expressions

... but *individually*.

Haskell doesn't have untagged union types. Haskell has tagged union types (these are searchable terms).

So the `Integer` value gets its own tag, `NumberI`, and the `Double` value gets its own tag, `NumberD`.

What you wrote in your data type definition, `Number (Integer, Double)`, means to have both `Integer` ***and*** `Double` *at the same time* in a value of type `Expr`.

But in your example you wrote `Number (5.2 :: Double)` and `Number 4` where you have *either* a `Double` (`5.2`), ***or*** what you presumably meant as an `Integer` (`4`) there, inside values of type `Expr`.