# How do I define a datatype Expr which has constructors Times | Plus | Number where Number can be of any type of Number (Int, Double, etc.) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I have to solve this question for my functional programming class:

> Define a polymorphic datatype `Expr` to represent expressions involving addition, multiplication and numbers.

`Expr` should have constructors `Times` | `Plus` | `Number` where `Number` can be of any type of number (`Int`, `Double`, etc.).

> In particular `expr1` and `expr2` should be accepted:
>
> ```
> expr1 = Times (Plus (Number (5.2 :: Double)) (Number 4)) (Number 2)
> expr2 = Plus (Number (2 :: Int)) (Times (Number 3) (Number 4))
> ```

How can I define it so that it accepts `Number 4` and `Number (5.2 :: Double)`?  It should be of type `Num` but I don't know how to define it so it takes any instance of `Num`.

Comment: `expr3 = Times (Number "hello") (Number "world")` what is this supposed to represent, in regards to multiplication/addition?

Comment: What should be the types of these expressions? Should `Number (2::Int)` have a different or the same type as `Number (5.2::Double)`? — Generally in any StackOverflow question you should show that you actually made an attempt at solving the problem yourself, and what didn't work.

Comment: expr3 does not have to be accepted, only 1 and 2

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be of type Num but I don't know how to define it so it takes any instance of Num.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794379/haskell-polymorphism-on-datatype ?

Comment: @chi there the answer was basically "do it monomorphically instead, with predefined set of possibilities". but here really the polymorphism seems to be [asked for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809166/how-do-i-define-a-datatype-expr-which-has-constructors-times-plus-number-whe#comment123399549_69809166) ("any instance of Num").

Comment: @WillNess You can't do much with "an unknown type of class `Num`". Given two values of this existential type, you can't sum them, for instance. I can't believe this is what the OP really wants, since we will never be able to write `eval :: Expr -> SomeNum` in any sensible way.

Comment: @chi the both of them used the word "polymorphic", so probably it was stated that way in the task. "impossible" is also an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that your examples don't require something like

```
Plus (Number (2 :: Int)) (Number (3 :: Double))
```

be accepted. In each example, *one* annotation seems to suffice to specify the concrete type of *all* `Number` values in the entire expression.

This means that all the concrete values behind the `Number` tag in one expression *are of the same type*, e.g.

```
Plus  (Number (2 :: Int))    (Number (3 :: Int))
Times (Number (2 :: Double)) (Number (3 :: Double))
```

This means we can abstract that type away as a *type variable*, making your data type definition *parametrically polymorphic* (as you wanted):

```
data Expr a = Time (Expr a) ....
            | Plus .... ....
            | Number a
```

As such, you would typically leave the *data type* unconstrained, as above, and add a `Num` constraint to any *function* that needs to operate on the values:

```
add :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
add = ...

eval :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a 
eval = ...
```

Since all the concrete `Number` values in the argument values are of the same type, calculating actual sums and products becomes possible, using `(+)` and `(*)` definitions from that type's instance of the `Num` class.